# Why does for loop exit before invalid substring checks?

Tags: java, string, for-loop, substring

I have this program that I wrote for my CS class in highschool. At first, I found no issues with it, and was happy that I was able to chunk in down to good size (unlike the kid next to me). Recently I realized that there should be an issue with the code. Let me give you background info.

The class is suppose to run through a string and remove all duplicate adjacent characters so that only one of them remains. So eeee just becomes e, and eeels becomes els.

My approach was to run though each index (except the last) and, if it finds duplicates, remove the current index. To work around 3+ adjacent characters, I reset the variable in the for loop back to -1 each time so that it will start at index 0 and look for another pair.

The issue that I feel like it should be having is that, if the string is simply the same character repeated, when it narrows in down to just a single character, it should still be trying to check for that and the next character, which would throw an error.

Because that most likely makes no sense, I put some print statements in the code to illustrate my point. Note that the string is held in the str instance variable, but the problem required it to remain the same, so I made a copy.

This is the code that I used in the method:

```
public String removeDups(){
    String copy = str;
    for(int x = 0; x < copy.length()-1; x++){
        System.out.println("Checking -> " + copy);
        if(copy.substring(x, x+1).equals(copy.substring(x+1, x+2))){
            copy = copy.substring(0, x) + copy.substring(x+1);
            //Restarts the search to make sure three characters in a row are adressed correctly
            x = -1;
        }
        System.out.println("New Copy -> " + copy);
        System.out.println(x + " < " + copy.length() + " == " + (x < copy.length()-1));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

and this was my test case for the issue I detected

```
ProblemX p5 = new ProblemX( "eee" );
s = p5.removeDups();
System.out.println( s );
s = p5.toString();
System.out.println( s );
```

This is what prints

```
Checking -> eee
New Copy -> ee
-1 < 2 == true
Checking -> ee
New Copy -> e
-1 < 1 == true //This is true, so it should loop again.
e //This is the weird thing, loop is broken.
eee
```

Where I marked the comment, the loop should have executed one more time (the condition was true), meaning that the code would break because it couldn't take a substring at index 2, but the code exited right there and went back to the main method totally fine.

While this obviously works, I would like an explination. Thanks.

EDIT: If the issue did arise, I know I could put the condition (copy.length()>=2) in the if statement to make sure that nothing happens when the string is too small, and the loop will eventually break.

Comment: From my experience, deleting the current index\object in collection is a bad idea. Maybe `Node<T>` is a good way to deal with cases where it's needed [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)

Comment: Your last print use `copy.length` but the loop use `length -1` and of course, x will be incremented at the end (after the print). So this seems logic for me (quick reading, might be mistaken). Basicly, you should write `System.out.println((x+1) + " < " + (copy.length() -1) + " == " + (x+1 < copy.length()-1));` to print the correct next condition

Comment: @ItamarGreen Sorry, but that doesn't make any sense. For one, we're dealing with Strings here, not collections; and then there's no need to use some XML-DOM classes for this simple string processing.

Comment: @JimmyB - notice, I sayed maybe... but you are quite right...

Comment: Tip: [`copy.charAt(x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) does the same as `copy.substring(x, x+1)`.

Comment: @AxelH pointed out the right solution and also why the loop seems "broken" to you. The increment happens at the end of the loop and then before the next iteration the condition is checked.

Comment: @JimmyB I absolutely would do that if I had the choice, but we are required to only use the methods he gave us.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your loop does not execute one more time is due to the conditional used by your `for` loop:

```
x < copy.length()-1
```

Typically, when iterating through a list of items, you would use:

```
x < copy.length()
```

or

```
x <= copy.length() - 1
```

However, your loop uses both `<` (as opposed to `<=`) and `copy.length() - 1` (as opposed to just `copy.length()`).  As a result, when `x` is 0 and `copy` is `e`, the loop conditional is `0 < 0`, which evaluates to `false`.

It is important to keep in mind that `x` is incremented *after* the loop has finished, which is why your check at the end of the loop returns true, but the following loop conditional returns false.